# "Expected KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP/KEXDH_REPLY" error using Chilkat library

Tags: sftp, chilkat

I am evaluating the new library of Chilkat SFTP.

However, I am getting an error as follows when connecting to an SFTP:

ChilkatLog:
  Connect_SFtp:
    DllDate: Aug 15 2013
    ChilkatVersion: 9.4.1.42
    UnlockPrefix: xxxxxxxx
    Username: (hidden)
    Architecture: Little Endian; 32-bit
    Language: .NET 2.0
    VerboseLogging: 0
    SftpVersion: 0
    hostname: xx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    port: 22
    ConnectTimeoutMs_1: 50000
    calling ConnectSocket2
    IPV6 enabled connect with NO heartbeat.
    This is an IPV4 numeric address...
    AddrInfoList:
      AddrInfo:
        ai_flags: 4
        ai_family: 2
        ai_socktype: 1
        ai_protocol: 0
        ai_addrlen: 16
        ai_canonname: (NULL)
      --AddrInfo
    --AddrInfoList
    Connect using IPV4.
    ipAddress1: xx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    myIP_3: xx.x.xxx.xx
    myPort_3: 50483
    connect successful (2)
    Established TCP/IP connection with SSH server
    Turning on TCP_NODELAY.
    clientIdentifier: SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Local:_May_11_2009_17:22:38
    Sending client identifier...
    Done sending client identifier.
    Reading server version...
    initialDataFromSshServer: SSH-2.0-0.0

```
serverVersion: SSH-2.0-0.0 
KeyExchangeAlgs:
  algorithm: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
  algorithm: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1
  algorithm: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
--KeyExchangeAlgs
HostKeyAlgs:
  algorithm: ssh-dss
--HostKeyAlgs
EncCS:
  algorithm: aes256-cbc
  algorithm: aes192-cbc
  algorithm: aes128-cbc
  algorithm: twofish-cbc
  algorithm: blowfish-cbc
  algorithm: 3des-cbc
  algorithm: arcfour
--EncCS
EncSC:
  algorithm: aes256-cbc
  algorithm: aes192-cbc
  algorithm: aes128-cbc
  algorithm: twofish-cbc
  algorithm: blowfish-cbc
  algorithm: 3des-cbc
  algorithm: arcfour
--EncSC
MacCS:
  algorithm: hmac-sha1
  algorithm: hmac-sha1-96
  algorithm: hmac-md5
  algorithm: hmac-md5-96
--MacCS
MacSC:
  algorithm: hmac-sha1
  algorithm: hmac-sha1-96
  algorithm: hmac-md5
  algorithm: hmac-md5-96
--MacSC
CompCS:
  algorithm: zlib
  algorithm: none
--CompCS
CompSC:
  algorithm: zlib
  algorithm: none
--CompSC
Encryption: 256-bit AES CBC
Encryption: 256-bit AES CBC
MAC: HMAC-SHA1
MAC: HMAC-SHA1
Compression: zlib
Compression: zlib
Key Exchange: DH Group Exchange SHA1
Host Key Algorithm: DSS
numBits: 160
pbits: 2048
Using GEX Group.
Sending KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST...
pbits: 2048
Unexpected message received.  Expected KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP/KEXDH_REPLY.
msgType: 1
Failed.
```

--Connect_SFtp
--ChilkatLog

---

I am primarily using the 4 functions to connect to SFTP

```
sftp.UnlockComponent(ChilkatKey);  
sftp.Connect(hostname, port);  
sftp.AuthenticatePw(username, password);  
sftp.InitializeSftp();
```

What am I missing ? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

correct order should be like as yours:

but after those guys, u need to call OpenDir and ReadDir(if you need to get files count on remote folder) methods like;

```
string handler = sftp.OpenDir("remote_path");
SFtpDir compassDir = sftp.ReadDir(handler);
```

to just download a file you don't need to call ReadDir but OpenDir must be called. After the populating compassDir object you can get file count by;

```
int fileAmount = compassDir.NumFilesAndDirs
```

or you can download files by name like;

```
sftp.DownloadFileByName("local_path","Remote_path_with_file_name");
```

Sorry for the typo errors.....